# IntelliJ IDEA solve inspect report

Tags: java, intellij-idea, inspect

IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2

Here is my code snippet:

```
    public int update(final String sql){
    int res = -1;
    try (Connection con = this.connect();
         Statement pst = con.createStatement() ){
        res=pst.executeUpdate(sql);//**if write pst.executeUpdate("") than no inspect message**
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.SEVERE,e.getMessage());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here is the inspect message:

> Call to 'Statement.executeUpdate()' with non-constant argument(short message)
>
> more
>
> Reports the calls to java.sql.Statement.executeUpdate() or any of its variants which take a dynamically-constructed string as the query to execute. Constructed SQL statements are a common source of security breaches

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The inspections hints you that it is better to use prepared statement. So instead of having a query like `UPDATE users SET name = "test" WHERE id ='1'`, you will end up with query like `UPDATE users SET name = ? WHERE id = ?`, and pass the needed parameters before executing it.

So in your case:

`PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
 // call pst.setInt(), pst.setString() etc. if needed
 pst.executeUpdate();`

See more details and examples in this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html